# ntpd fails to sync TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized

Tags: ntp, ntpd

On Debian 10, `ntpd 4.2.8p12@1.3728-o` fails to sync with following error:

```
kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronize
```

here's `ntp.conf`:

```
disable monitor

statsdir /var/log/ntpstats

restrict -4 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

server 0.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.us.pool.ntp.org iburst

server   127.127.1.0
fudge    127.127.1.0 stratum 10
restrict 127.127.1.0

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
```

`ntpq -c sysinfo`:

```
associd=0 status=0614 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, freq_mode,
system peer:        50-205-57-38-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net:123
system peer mode:   client
leap indicator:     00
stratum:            2
log2 precision:     -23
root delay:         70.634
root dispersion:    3.569
reference ID:       50.205.57.38
reference time:     e3a0c049.c39d770a  Wed, Jan  6 2021 23:03:37.764
system jitter:      0.723169
clock jitter:       1.177
clock wander:       0.000
broadcast delay:    -50.000
symm. auth. delay:  0.000
```

`ntpq -c lpeers`:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l  286   64   20    0.000    0.000   0.000
*50-205-57-38-st .GPS.            1 u   19   64   37   70.631    1.618   1.843
-ns1.backplanedn 173.162.192.156  2 u   14   64   37   84.235   -1.575   2.852
+c-73-239-136-18 74.6.168.73      3 u   11   64   37   48.606    1.598   2.522
+time-d.bbnx.net 252.74.143.178   2 u   14   64   37   92.632    0.623   0.799
```

`timedatectl`:

```
               Local time: Wed 2021-01-06 23:06:44 UTC
           Universal time: Wed 2021-01-06 23:06:44 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2021-01-06 23:06:44
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Probably nothing is wrong, and it's just a misleading warning message at startup. See, for example, https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ntpd-kernel-reports-time_error-0x2041-clock-unsynchronized-4175636606/#post5892946. Apart from this message, are there any other symptoms that worry you? Is the time correct? This computer seems to get its time from a GPS device, and the difference between GPS time and computer time is a mere millisecond (offset column in the peers table).

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried about kernel reporting unsynced clock. `ntp` seems to need more time to sync. I've tried using `chrony` and it reports synced time immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your clock is syncing fine.  The `sync_ntp` in your `ntpq -c sysinfo` proves that.  The kernel messages you're referring to are transient during `ntpd` startup and are not anything to be worried about.

The problems I see with your setup:

1. `timedatectl` is not reporting time sync correctly.  The easy fix for that is not to run it. :-)  On one of my servers on the same OS and NTP version, `timedatectl` doesn't produce anything useful at all, but instead says `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory`, because I don't run `dbus`.
2. I'm surprised your configuration works with pool servers at all, because of the lack of a `restrict source ...` line.
3. You're using the LOCL clock driver, which has been deprecated for many years.
4. Similarly, you don't need `disable monitor` to protect yourself from being used for reflective DDoS - the default `restrict` lines handle that.

You should revert to the default Debian `/etc/ntp.conf` contents - it will work better than your current configuration and cause you fewer problems when you upgrade.  Here's a copy, in case you don't have one handy: http://paste.debian.net/1180011/

Answer (score -1):

I've had a **multi-second time drift** and similar error messages and I've solved it with:

```
systemctl stop ntpd
systemctl start ntpdate  # takes some seconds to succeed
systemctl start ntpd
```

After that, the time drift was gone. Solution taken from [opensuse forums here](https://forum.opnsense.org/index.php?topic=18557.0)

Comment: There is usually never a need to run this - `ntpd` is usually started with the `-g` flag on modern systems, which will do what `ntpdate` does, but without needing to use a deprecated utility.

Comment: @PaulGear "usually never"? I had to run this on my ArchLinux system this year. Especially strange to see criticism of my answer that I've written because *it worked on my system, and the other solutions I was trying did not* -- all while you have your own answer above as well.

Comment: * I've now edited my answer to be clear(er) on the fact that the time drift was real -- not just the error messages.

Comment: I guess my wording could use some work as well. I would have said "never" because all distros I'm familiar with start `ntpd` with `-g`, which will step the clock up to 1000 seconds on startup, but I don't know about the default settings on all distros. :-)